# Segmented control in react native doesn't contain the same value in event and my state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, uisegmentedcontrol, segmentedcontrol

I have issue with SegmentedControl component in React Native.

```
<SegmentedControlIOS style={styles.SegmentedControlIOS}
    values={['All', 'Recent']}
    selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
    onChange={this._handleChangeSegment.bind(this)}
/>

_handleChangeSegment(event) {
    console.log(event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex, "nativeEvent");
    this.setState({
        isLoading: true,
        selectedIndex: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex
    });
    console.log(this.state.selectedIndex, "state");
    this.fetchData();
}
```

The problem here is the value of nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex and my selectedIndex state, in the console I have :

By default selectedIndex state is set to 1 (Recent) in the constructor.
When I click 'All' the console.log return

0, 'nativeEvent'
1, 'state'

So the nativeEvent is correct but it seems not to be updated in my state and I don't know why.
Could you please help me with that ?

In the fetchData method I check if the selectedIndex state is 1 or 0 to call an ajax request but it doesn't load the good request because the state value is not the nativeEvent.selectedSegmentedIndex.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

From https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state    transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value.

Therefore, console.log(this.state.selectedIndex, "state") is not necessarily going to return the mutated state.

If you need access to the mutated state, you can pass a callback function as a second argument to setState - this callback function will be executed after the state has been mutated.